# Plotting Heatmap on xyz data

Tags: gnuplot

I need to create a color-map ( heat-map) on this xyz datafile.

```
16.4645 -8.19898 -12.8904
-15.8086 -14.2834 8.16466
-22.1801 0.829724 -12.9072
-23.2899 -0.766454 -0.856553
-9.70407 -9.05421 18.1793
-20.7488 10.0369 6.15957
-22.0808 11.1614 -3.49831
-6.04398 -22.1432 -11.1618
-6.34688 -22.8299 7.09053
-4.06349 -12.694 -20.75
-12.3437 8.67375 -16.5742
```

The problem is, when I use

```
plot "lastframe.dat" using 1:2:3 with image t ''
```

I get the following error

```
warning: Number of pixels cannot be factored into integers matching grid. N = 60  K = 25
warning: Number of pixels cannot be factored into integers matching grid. N = 60  K = 25
```

Is there a way to plot using pm3d and get a color-map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a color map using pm3d, try this:

```
set pm3d map
set dgrid3d                             
splot "lastframe.dat" using 1:2:3
```

Check out http://lowrank.net/gnuplot/plot3d-e.html for useful tips and tricks.